# Locating Coordinate Reference System Selector on QGIS

Tags: qgis

I downloaded the latest version of GQIS last Friday(6/3/15). I can't locate the Coordinate Reference System Selector. 
I have tried clicking settings, custom CRS, add CRS, but can't find a way to proceed from there. Any help?

Comment: Do you want to set the project CRS? Then you need to go to project properties.